# Why can't I just declare all methods static?

Tags: java

I was being questioned by this, why can't I declare all methods static? Can you give me a piece of explanation in here? Thanks.

I believe that when you make a method static, it cannot access non-static members?

Comment: you can but you should not

Comment: *"Can you give me a piece of explanation in here?"* Can you show some effort by doing research and summarizing what ***you*** think the answer is?

Comment: if everything is static - instantiating objects is useless. This is good for Static Utility libraries

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil

Comment: @assylias thanks for this! I'll read this one.

Comment: @openCage Why? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572117/why-dont-we-make-everything-static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static methods cannot access instance variables. :)

```
public class MyStaticExample{
  private String instanceVariable = "Hello";
  private static String STATIC_VARIABLE = "Hello too";

  public static void staticMethod(){
    System.out.println(this.instanceVariable); // this will result in a compilation error.
    System.out.println(STATIC_VARIABLE); // this is ok
  }

  public void instanceMethod(){
    System.out.println(this.instanceVariable); // this is ok
    System.out.println(STATIC_VARIABLE); // this is ok
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you give me an example of this? :) thanks

Comment: Then why not just declare all variables static?

Comment: This is not a valid answer at all.

Answer (score 5):

You can. There would be no reason to instantiate objects from such a class. Any state would be global across the JVM.

Your questioner was perhaps confusing "can't" with "shouldn't".

Comment: *Any state would be global across the JVM.* nay, you  can have normal classes w/ static methods that take the said classes and access the fields (just like C struct). As a "benefit" there won't be overridden methods

Comment: OK, granted. Also `ThreadLocal`s.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** declare all method as `static` but then your method will become class level. Let say you create 10 objects have different states where state is held by `properties`. Then in this case you ***will not be*** able to get the `state` of objects by using `static` methods .

```
Object obj;
public static Object getState(){

    return obj; // compile time error Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field 
}
```

Making all methods static is good practice in **Utility Classes** .

Comment: I thought `obj` was already static though, as it belongs to class `Object`, right? Please let me know. +1 :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572117/why-dont-we-make-everything-static

Answer (score 2):

You can. But the result would be a structured program (think C, Pascal) using existing classes, not real OOP. Object orientation is the idiomatic approach to Java programming, so keep the number of static keywords in your code low.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572117/why-dont-we-make-everything-static

Answer (score 2):

I would start with Lesson: [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) and pick almost any class from the JDK. A simple one to start with is [Boolean](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Boolean.java?av=f) which needs two instances, one for TRUE and one for FALSE which can't be implemented using static methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572117/why-dont-we-make-everything-static

Answer (score 1):

There is no restraint like that. You can make all methods in a class static. In C# you can even define a class itself as static (requiring all methods in it to be static).

It is more a question of what you want to achieve with that class.

Answer (score 1):

You can define all methods as static. It depends on the context whether you should or shouldn't. Best option is to make static library method. For example below is a TestHelper utility class I have created-

```
public class TestHelper {
    /**
     * Method echo.
     * 
     * @param heading
     *            String
     */
    public static void echo(String heading) {
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.println("++++++ " + heading + " ++++++");
    }

    public static void end() {
        System.out.println("=========================");
    }

    public static void mark() {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    }

    /**
     * Method spot.
     * 
     * @param string
     *            String
     */
    public static void spot(Object string) {
        System.out.println("*****_______" + string + "_______******");
    }

    /**
     * This is a stub method
     */
    public static void stub() {

    }

    public static void error(String string) {
        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^Error Begining^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
        System.out.println(string);
        System.out.println("^^^^^^^^^^^Error End^^^^^^^");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572117/why-dont-we-make-everything-static

Answer (score 0):

You can declare everything static. But what kind of normal scale object model would need all methods static , is a big question

Comment: Why not, wouldn't it save you the time to make objects? Can't you just call methods using the class instance that way? And access variables using the class instance? What is the point of objects then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572117/why-dont-we-make-everything-static

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can depends upon your need. But remember "this" keyword will not work in this case you can not access to public members!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572117/why-dont-we-make-everything-static